# Waiting for a event to be fired in a function

Tags: c#, .net, events

I have the following event & function:

```
    static void rViewer_DocumentLoaded(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Do something
    }

    static RadPdfViewer rViewer = new RadPdfViewer();
    static RadPrintDocument rpd = new RadPrintDocument();

    internal static bool PrintReportBlocking(string sFileName, REPORT_TYPE reportType)      
    {
        try
        {

            rpd = new RadPrintDocument();
            rViewer = new RadPdfViewer();
            rViewer.LoadDocument(sFileName);
            rViewer.DocumentLoaded += rViewer_DocumentLoaded;

            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

My goal is to block in the function, until the event is fired.

Comment: Yeah, probably no.  You'll end up blocking the UI thread and that'll block the print job and you'll end up deadlocked.  Better to [edit] and tell us what you're doing and what you want to happen and why you believe "block"ing the method is a solution.

Comment: You could probably rewrite this as an async/await thing. You certainly don't want to block the UI thread while this is working.

Comment: The "PrintReportBlocking" function can be called 5 times in a row and the problem is, that the event is getting overwritten and the printer prints the same document 5 times.

Comment: @xileb0 - You are attaching the event **after** calling `LoadDocument`. It's too late then. You need to do it before. And if the `DocumentLoaded` event runs on the current thread then this will automatically block.

Comment: I changed this. Does not change anything.
But how could I achieve this?

Answer (score -1):

You can use an AutoResetEvent:

```
static void rViewer_DocumentLoaded(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    are.Set();
    //Do something
}

static RadPdfViewer rViewer = new RadPdfViewer();
static RadPrintDocument rpd = new RadPrintDocument();
static AutoResetEvent are = new AutoResetEvent(false);
internal static bool PrintReportBlocking(string sFileName, REPORT_TYPE reportType)
{
    try
    {

        rpd = new RadPrintDocument();
        rViewer = new RadPdfViewer();
        rViewer.DocumentLoaded += rViewer_DocumentLoaded;
        rViewer.LoadDocument(sFileName);
        are.WaitOne();
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried it like that, but the event never gets fired, when I do it like that. Could it be a problem that this is in WinForms?

Comment: I am not familiar with RadPdfViewer. Have you tried to set a breakpoint on the setting of the AutoResetEvent to try and see if the code gets executed?

Comment: are.Set() is not executed -> I think the event is not fired, because the program blocks at are.WaitOne()

Comment: Is this not exactly what you wanted ? The blocking part blocks on the autoreset event, and is waiting for the rViewer_DocumentLoaded function to set the AutoResetEvent.

You program is blocking because rViewer_DocumentLoaded is never called. If I were you, and to avoid concurrency issues, I'd invert the LoadDocument line and the event subscription (see my edited example), to avoid cases where the document is loaded before you subscribe to the event.

Comment: I changed the two lines, the event is still not fired.
When I do not use the AutoResetEvent, it is fired.

Answer (score -1):

You can use TaskCompletionSource to achieve this:

```
static RadPdfViewer rViewer = new RadPdfViewer();
static RadPrintDocument rpd = new RadPrintDocument();

internal static bool PrintReportBlocking(string sFileName, REPORT_TYPE reportType)      
{
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<object>();
    try
    {
        rpd = new RadPrintDocument();
        rViewer = new RadPdfViewer();
        rViewer.DocumentLoaded += () => tcs.SetResult(null);
        rViewer.LoadDocument(sFileName);

        // If you really want to block, but you should probably use async/await
        tcs.Task.Wait();

        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't really understand this. Where is the DocumentLoaded-Event bound?

Comment: () => tcs.SetResult(null) is a closure, it's an equivalent of a named method like your rViewer_DocumentLoaded, just with an implicit access to parent's variables (tcs), while in a named method you would need to explicitly pass the object.